# jupyter notebook: download as html with iframes

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

I have a notebook that loads local html fiels with

```
IFrame(src='./products.html', width=800, height=600)
```

With the notebook open I see the contents of `products.html` but when I click “Download as” and select html within the Jupyter Notebook web application and open the generated html file, I see the message

> It may have been moved or deleted.

where `products.html` should be.

Is there a way to export a notebook including static html files?

Comment: Have you looked at [nbconvert](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)?

Comment: @JohnSzakmeister I already use "Download as" which is the nbconvert feature, right?

Comment: can you share the contents of the folder where your downloaded jupyter notebook is ?

Comment: Yep, it looks that way. :-(

Answer (score -1):

You can try saving it as slides. I find it the most reliable form. 
[image]

Comment: in this export i cant even figure out how to scroll to the bottom of the document to check whether the `products.html` is included

Comment: zoom out. it saves it in a single slide.